# PHP fatal error opening required

Tags: php, iis

I've copied php and IIS files to new PC and can't bring it to work. Everytime getting this error:

> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '-' (include_path:.;C:\PHP\includes)

So, what IS THIS -> '-'? My index.php just contain only two strings, it's `<?php` and `phpinfo();`

Comment: Is IIS configured to run PHP?

Comment: Yes, module binded. index.php set as default document. On PC #1 everything works well, on PC #2 - fails. Same files, same settings.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems may occur when you use IIS under WIndows OS due to a misunderstanding of the file paths that contain non-Latin characters . Check the file path for the presence of non-Latin characters . Also try to change the encoding utf8 script - cp1251

Comment: The index.php script was copied right from machine where it has worked well for a long time. Php.ini and all php files too. It's definitely IIS, but I don't know way to dig deep.

Answer (score 0):

For the information of anyone else who encounters this problem, I was attempting to use php 7.1 on Windows 10 and IIS using localhost.

I had only a test page containing a single phpinfo() command, but when I attempt to navigate to this page, I got:

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '-' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

In my case, the handler mapping in iis was mis-configured.

Start IIS and under Double Click Handler mappings.

[image]

Select the entry for *.php and click Edit in the actions menu.

[image]

Change php.exe to php-cgi.exe as shown below.

[image]

You might also like to look at this page which explains things in a bit more detail:

http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.iis7.php

Regards.
Chris B.